# How to make a program in java that does not wait for the input from user not more than 2 or 3 seconds

Tags: multithreading, java.util.scanner, keypress

I am creating a game for testing the typing skill of the user. In this I want my program not to wait for the user input after some specific seconds(2-3 seconds). So the program should wait for user input for 2 or 3 seconds, then if the user does not press any key (not even Enter  key) program should do some specific task.How to make this type of interactive program in java.. I tried implementing concepts of multi threading but couldn't get the expected output..

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class IsKeyPressed {
   private static volatile boolean wPressed = false;

   public static boolean isWPressed() {
      synchronized (IsKeyPressed.class) {
          return wPressed;
      }
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
          .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
            synchronized (IsKeyPressed.class) {
                switch (ke.getID()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                        wPressed = true;
                    }
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                        wPressed = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                return false;
               }
           }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: please share a minimal example of what you've tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how

Comment: Could you please share the section of the code which needs to be executed after 3 seconds or once user presses the expected key?